# Button on HTML page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have an HTML page. I use the button to navigate on this page. But in the 2 section where there are slides, the button doesn't work. 
I try to solve it for hour, but I don't understand the problem. You can find the site [here](http://www.autoelettric.com/info/SafeConversionToLed.html).

And you can find the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MarikaF/6LmLp5m2/1/).

Here there are the part html:

```
<div class="section" id="section5">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>#your Led Solution 1 of 2</h1>
            <br><br>
            <p>Use an ILS LED Flasher Unit, connecting an ILS booster for each LED indicator lamp in the circuit</p>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DQ2i9iz.png" class="imgProduct" alt="ILS LED Flasher Unit and ILS booster" style="height:350px;">
            <div id="type2">
            <a href="http://www.autoelettric.com/index.php/en/products/i-ls-intelligent-led-solutions-en"><div class="btn-5" width="50px">→ VIEW PRODUCT</div></a>
            <br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <a href="#ExactPower" onclick="status2()"><div class="btn-5-previous" width="50px">↩ PREVIOUS</div></a>
        <a href="#SafeConversion" onclick="status0()"><div class="btn-5-top" width="10px">↑</div></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>#your Led Solution 2 of 2</h1>
            <br><br>
            <p>Use an ILS LED Flasher Unit &#38; LED indicator lamps with integrated pulse</p>
            <img src="http://www.autoelettric.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/ils-led-flasher-2022H4ILS.png" class="imgProduct" alt="ILS LED Flasher Unit & LED indicator lamps" style="height:350px;">
            <div id="type2">
            <a href="http://www.autoelettric.com/index.php/en/products/i-ls-intelligent-led-solutions-en"><div class="btn-5" width="50px">→ VIEW PRODUCT</div></a>
            <br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <a href="#ExactPower" onclick="status2()"><div class="btn-5-previous" width="50px">↩ PREVIOUS</div></a>
        <a href="#SafeConversion" onclick="status0()"><div class="btn-5-top" width="10px">↑</div></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#ExactPower" onclick="status2()"><div class="btn-5-previous" width="50px">↩ PREVIOUS</div></a>
    <a href="#SafeConversion" onclick="status0()"><div class="btn-5-top" width="10px">↑</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific which button does not work, because I tested the provided link with Mozilla Firefox and it works fine.

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer try to click "back to top" in this page http://www.autoelettric.com/info/SafeConversionToLed.html#YourSolution2 or "prevoius" in this page http://www.autoelettric.com/info/SafeConversionToLed.html#YourSolution2/1

Comment: Yeah exactly which button be more specific?

Comment: okay got it let me see.

Comment: Even the slide button to go back(<) doesn't work on my browser

Comment: you have duplicate id's in the code (<div id="type2">) - you need to make all id's unique.

Comment: @MarikaF. 

The problem is probably your browser because the "Back to Top"- Button as well as all the other Buttons are working for me. What browser are you using and have you checked whether you allowed to execute JavaScript in your browser?

Comment: @gavgrif I create a new type3 with the same property and I change with type2, but doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer "Back to top Button" work, but "↑" in #YourSolution2 no. And also "Previous" in #YourSolution2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- .fp-slides has z-index: 1; which place it on the top of back-to-button, so either remove z-index value of .fp-slides or add z-index to back-to-top button.
- Also there is another set of #ExactPower and #SafeConversion buttons inside .fp-slides .slides.

Comment: Thanks, I removed z index!